# How convert char* to float xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite, floating-point

I need convert 'field' in float type. How can do?

```
        char *field = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statment, 1);
```

Comment: Is the database field actually a string or a float/double?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the floating point value is stored in a string column, you can use the `sqlite3_column_double` function of SQLite:

```
float field = (float)sqlite3_column_double(statement, 1);
```

SQLite will do an automatic conversion for you, but using a column of a floating-point type would be a better choice.

Comment: The column type doesn't matter; `sqlite3_column_xxx` converts automatically.

Comment: @CL. Thanks for the comment! I edited my answer to reflect your point.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done this way as well if you are converting numeric value.

```
        char c = 0x010;
        char* ch = &c;
        float f = ((float)(*ch));
        float* fl = &f;
        printf("\n%f\n",*fl);
```